# What is dollar sign within directory location?

Tags: stata

I got a Stata do file which always uses "dollar" sign $ whenever "using" something.

But when I actually run it on my computer, it looks like my computer thinks the directory is ignored.

[image]

Here, the directory "logs" was just ignored and obviously my computer thinks I am looking for the file in the main directory "C"

What is that dollar sign? Why does my computer think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dollar signs are here used to refer to Stata macros.

Stata sees here a reference to a global macro. `$global` would be a reference to a global macro that has the name `global`. If a macro is not defined, that is not in itself illegal, and Stata substitutes an empty string. `log`'s default, it seems, in this case is to write in the root directory.

Here the consequence is not what you want, as evidently you don't have a `C:` drive or (perhaps more likely) don't have permission to write in it. (There is no precise information in your post about your set-up, although it can be guessed that you are using Windows.)

You can define a global such as

```
global logs "c:\whatever\wherever"
```

and then

```
log using $logs\df.log
```

would be interpreted as

```
log using c:\whatever\wherever\df.log
```

If you prefer just use your own direct specification to specify where a log file should be opened:

```
log using c:\whatever\wherever\df.log
```

Nothing in Stata stops you specifying any other drive that exists and to which you have write access.

For more on global macros, see [e.g. this manual chapter](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u18.pdf).